# cdfs $F$ and $G$ of random variable $X$, $F\le G$. What can we say about $\mathbb{E}_F[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}_G[X]$?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

**Problem:** A random variable $X$ is distributed in $[0,1]$. Mr. Fox believes that $X$ follows a distribution with cumulative density function $F:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ and Mr. Goat believes that $X$ follows a distribution with cdf $G:[0,1]\to [0,1]$. Assume $F$ and $G$ are differentiable, $F\ne G$ and $F(x)\le G(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Let $\mathbb{E}_F[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}_G[X]$ be the expected values of $X$ for Mr. Fox and Mr. Goat respectively. Is $\mathbb{E}_F[X]$ $\ge$, $\le$, or $ =$ $\mathbb{E}_G[X]$?

How do I relate expectation with cdf? Please give hints.

Comment: Since your random variable is non-negative, you can use the formula $\mathbb E_F[X] = \int_0^\infty P_F(X \geq x) \, \mathrm{d} x$ and use the definition of cdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for a non-negative random variable $X$, we have $E X = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) \; dx$ and then the conclusion should be obvious.  \

That formula can be shown as follows, using a usual trick with change of order of integration:
$$
  E X = \int_0^\infty x f(x) \; dx = \int_0^\infty \int_0^x \;dt f(x)\; dx \\
      = \int_0^\infty \int_t^\infty f(x) \; dx\; dt \\
      = \int_0^\infty (1-F(t)) \; dt
$$

Comment: Could you explain the intuition behind this formula?

Comment: I will add a derivation to the answer, using a change of order of integration.

Comment: The proof of the formula presented in the answer relies on the existence of a PDF although the formula is valid in full generality.

Comment: That is true, and the general result can be proven the same way by changing to the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral.